# WPF - window.IsEnabled setter long duration

Tags: wpf, window, duration

I have a question about Window.IsEnabled property in WPF - C# 5.0, .NET4.5.

I have following scenario (simplified):

1) form with button

2) user triggers a long-computing operation (fetching some data from DB)

3) user is able to interact with new data

I have implemented this following way:

1) the Click handler **DISABLES** the window (for user interaction) and fires asynchronously the operation (this can be made synchronously, it doesn't matter)

2) when the async op is done, the windows is **ENABLED** (via **myWindowInstance.IsEnabled = true**)

And my problem is:

The myWindowInstance.IsEnabled = true takes about 20 seconds. I must note there is a dataGridView in the window for fetched data. However, without disabling and re-enabling the win this all takes about 1s. Another interesting point is, when I'm connected to small local DB, the win.IsEnabled setter is done quickly. Opposite to this, if I use remote huge DB, this op takes, as mentioned, 20s. And in both cases I fetch just 100 rows.

Does anybody have any idea why simple setter takes so large amount of time?

Lot of thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Hi did you get around this or found the reason for this behaviour? I have similar experiences...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do instead of disabling your window is to just enable/disable a semi-transparent Rectangle you inserted on top of other controls, user won't be able to click anything.
When you're done, either disable it or set its Visibility property to Hidden.

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="Hello" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" ></TextBox>
        <Rectangle Fill="DarkGray" Opacity="0.5" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now regarding the large amount of time it takes for your issue, you should profile your application using the 'Analyze' menu in Visual Studio.